# how to define global variable in vscode debug

Tags: vscode-debugger

I define global var in my code, like `__DEV__`, It can build by webpack tool. But when i press "F5" to debug the code, it runs error.

```
error msg: Cannot find name '__DEV__'.
```

```
// .vscode/launch.json
{
    "name": "TS File",
    "type": "node",
    "request": "launch",
    "args": [
      "${workspaceRoot}/test/index.ts"
    ],
    "runtimeArgs": [
      "--nolazy",
      "-r",
      "ts-node/register",
    ],
    "sourceMaps": true,
    "cwd": "${workspaceRoot}",
    "protocol": "inspector",
    "console": "integratedTerminal",
    "internalConsoleOptions": "neverOpen"
},

// webpack.config.js
plugins: [
    new webpack.DefinePlugin({
        __DEV__: JSON.stringify(false),
    })
],
```

Comment: I don't know what you think you are doing but, your stringify'ing the boolean value false, and then it looks like your trying to pass it in as you Webpack configuration.

Comment: If your webpack config is in your rootdir you shouldn't need to target its path, however; if it is not in the rootdir, then the way you pass it in is with the **`luanch.json`'s** **Args Properties Array**. Somthin like this: **` "args": ["--config", "./.../webpack.config.js"],`**

Answer (score 1):

Just declare it somewhere, better at the entry point.

```
declare global {
  var __DEV__;
}
```